# Strip a date from varchar field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar field such as 'Created by blogs 16/10/2014 #123456 more stuff'.

I have stripped out the characters e.g. stuff(Col, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', Col)-1, '') and also replaced the #, so that I am left with 16/10/2016 123456.

I now want to remove the date.  The date could be positioned before or after the 123456.  The date may be in various formats.

My end goal is to be left with 123456.

Comment: You could look into substring functions. If you can get the index of the space, maybe you can use a substring from that position forward.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  I think I will struggle to use substring with the space, as the number I require may be before or after the space, I don't know which, as it is a free format field and the users follow no rules!

Comment: Well unless you can identify some rules to identify the desired text you won't be able to program this.

Comment: Is the number always preceded by `'#'`?

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you Martin that this is difficult to program for, as this is a free format text box and the number won't always be preceded by a hash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It assumes that the number is prefixed with '#' and followed by a space (or is last).:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100)
SET @Str = 'Created by blogs 16/10/2014 #123456 more stuff'

SELECT
  SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX('#', @Str) + 1, 999), 
            1, 
            CHARINDEX(' ', 
                      SUBSTRING(@Str + ' ', 
                                CHARINDEX('#', @Str) + 1, 999)))
```

Replace @Str with your column name.   Added a bugfix for when the number is last

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)
SET @YourString = 'Created by blogs 16/10/2014 #123456 more stuff'

SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@YourString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@YourString)-1),CHARINDEX(' ',RIGHT(@YourString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@YourString)-1)))
```